# frameowrk7-vue unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, phonegap-build, html-framework-7

I have a phonegap application build with framework7-vue and I would like to write some tests.

I have looked online for an example and I could not find any.
I know how to use mocha and chai on functions and raw javascript, but with phonegap it's just not working.

Can someone please give an example or share a link on how unit testing can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "not working"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Well, to be honest, I don't know how to start with testing the phonegap application, I tried to see examples online but they are all different, I am not looking for ready code, just some guidance will be more than enough and apologies for the late reply.